# Check if ActiveX label contains part of string

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am using this code to hide a label based on if it contains % sign only and nothing else.

It is this part of the code it is erroring now when running. Error: "OLEFormat.Object: Invalid Request. Command cannot be applied to a shape range with multiple shapes"

What should be the correct code?

```
If InStr(1, myRange.OLEFormat.Object.Caption, "%", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
```

---

```
Sub c_Three_RemovePercent()

For slideNumber = 1 To 11

Set mydocument = ActivePresentation.Slides(slideNumber)
mydocument.Select

Dim myArray() As Variant
Dim myRange As Object
myArray = Array("Lbl_V1", "Lbl_V2", "Lbl_V3", "Lbl_V4", "Lbl_V5")
Set myRange = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.Range(myArray)



With mydocument.Shapes.Range(myArray)


 If InStr(1, myRange.OLEFormat.Object.Caption, "%", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
    mydocument.Shapes(myRange).Visible = False
       Else: mydocument.Shapes(myRange).Visible = True
   End If


  End With


    Next slideNumber
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

All these blindfolded late-bound member calls are easily confusing: you don't get *IntelliSense* to help you navigate the available members.

You're looking for an `OLEObject`, so declare one; assign it:

```
Dim oleLabel As Excel.OLEObject
Set oleLabel = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("SomeShapeName").OLEFormat.Object
```

Now you want the control that's in that `OLEObject`'s `Object` property, and you want to cast that control to its `MSForms.Label` interface:

```
Dim labelControl As MSForms.Label
Set labelControl = oleLabel.Object
```

Now you have an early-bound `MSForms.Label` interface to query, and *IntelliSense* guides you all the way:

```
If Contains(labelControl.Caption, "%") Then
    '...
Else
    '...
End If
```

Where `Contains` could look something like this:

```
Public Function Contains(ByVal source As String, ByVal substring As String) As Boolean
    Contains = InStr(1, source, substring, vbTextCompare) > 0
End Function
```

---

You have an array of label control names you want to iterate - just iterate it:

```
Dim labelNames As Variant
labelNames = Array("label1", "label2", "label3", ...)

Dim i As Long
For i = LBound(labelNames) To UBound(labelNames)
    Set oleLabel = currentSlide.Shapes(labelNames(i)).OLEObject
    oleLabel.Visible = Not Contains(labelControl.Caption, "%")
Next
```

Note how this:

```
If BooleanExpression Then
    Thing = True
Else
    Thing = False
End If
```

Can be rewritten as:

```
Thing = BooleanExpression
```

Comment: hello Mathieu, with this part...Dim oleLabel As Excel.OLEObject why Excel.OLEObject?

Comment: Because that's what the type of `OLEFormat.Object` is =)

Comment: it's giving an error... "User defined type not defined. " Also with this line Set oleLabel = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("SomeShapeName").OLEFormat.Object What should I replace "SomeShapeName" with. I have 4 Shapes

Comment: Don't just copy-paste the code blocks, *read* the answer. *You have an array of label control names you want to iterate - just iterate it*. That `For` loop iterates the array of names.

Answer (score 0):

For checking if string contains the vba function [INSTR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/instr-function) is typically best. Basically in the below example... Starting in the first position, check this text, look for "%", case insensative.

```
  If InStr(1, myRange.OLEFormat.Object.Caption, "%", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
       mydocument.Shapes(myRange).Visible = False
       Else: mydocument.Shapes(myRange).Visible = True
   End If
```

Comment: I tried this but it's giving an error "Expected Then or Go To"

Comment: It must not be string (text) then.  If you stop your code right before that line and hit `Debug.Print myRange.OLEFormat.Object.Caption` you should get the text.

Comment: Once I have copied and pasted the code this line                                                
If InStr(1, myRange.OLEFormat.Object.Caption, "%", vbTextCompare), "%") > 0 Then           goes red. There is some sort of syntax error. I can't seem to figure it out. I have tried to write the code in my self but no luck

Comment: ACK sorry. `If InStr(1, myRange.OLEFormat.Object.Caption, "%", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then` I will correct answer

Comment: Thanks this worked. I have changed the original question with the updated code. But getting a different error now, when running.

Comment: @Camille I saw that one coming. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53605702/1188513).

Comment: Why use an `If` statement to set a `Boolean` value?   `mydocument.Shapes(myRange).Visible = InStr(1, myRange.OLEFormat.Object.Caption, "%", vbTextCompare) < 0` seems more reasonable.